# Null Safety equivalent of "List<List<T>>()"?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

My old working code:
`List<List<T>> pages = List<List<T>>();`

Now doesn't work with null safety:

The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled.
Try using a list literal, 'List.filled' or 'List.generate'.dartdefault_list_constructor
'List' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use a list literal, [], or the List.filled constructor instead.

Comment: The error you posted mentions the solution. More in-depth explanation in the official docs here: https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#default_list_constructor

Comment: In your case you would want to use `List<List<T>> pages = [<T>[]];` or perhaps even just `var pages = [<T>[]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// @dart=2.12
void doSomething<T>() {
  List<List<T>> pages = [];
  print(pages.runtimeType.toString());
}

void main() {
  doSomething<String>();
}
```

Result

```
JSArray<List<String>>
```